# Weird behaviour with Hebrew as gibberish ׳¨׳•׳

Tags: asp.net, utf-8, character-encoding

I am sending requests using ASP.net to a third party invoice service which insert the company's details into db and later on shows the company info in the company's invoices. The problem is that if the company's name is in hebrew I see it in the invoice as gibberish. I tried encoding the company's name:

```
  var companyName = "רומן";
  var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(companyName);
  var encodedCompanyName = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

as welll as adding a utf encoding header to the request:

```
 client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
```

I also tried adding globalization to the web.config:

```
<globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" culture="he-IL" />
```

Nothing seems to help. The thing is that we have an old project written is ASP classic which does work fine (with hebrew on company's name) against the same third party provider. I checked the code there but no special encoding in the request. I understood from the third party support that from my new project it gets into their db as gibberish.

Comment: What gibberish are you seeing - is it `×¨×•×ž×Ÿ` ?  Your Hebrew is hardcoded into the file - have you actually saved the file as UTF8?

Comment: @John yes like so:  ׳¨׳•׳׳   ,  I don't have a file but I am sending the data to a third party which insert it to db..

Comment: The line which begins `var companyName = "רומן";` is presumably in a file on your server?

Comment: @john yes it is written in my .cs file code.

Comment: OK, you need to check if your .cs file is saved as UTF8.  If you open it in a text editor such as Notepad++ or EditPlus (or even the basic Notepad progam which ships with Windows) and select "Save As" from the File menu, you'll find an "Encoding" drop down. If something other than UTF8 is selected then change it to UTF8.  It's possible to do this in Visual Studio too, but the relevant drop down is harder to find, and it seems to change from version.

Comment: Slight amendment to that - in Notepad++  the encoding dropdown is on the top menu

Comment: @John it is saved as UTF8 + BOM

Comment: @John I have changed it to UTF8 but the problem persist :/